# How do we break out of paralysis?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions

Our party is all fifth level and consists of a Barbarian, Druid, Rogue, Ranger, and Fighter.

We fought a group of large spear-using centauroid insects with a scorpion-like stinger. The stinger attack inflicted the *[poisoned](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Poisoned) condition*, but caused no further damage. When each character was defeated, the creature injected more poison, which stabilized the victim but inflicted the *[paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Paralyzed) condition* as well.

We killed the creatures, battle is over, and the DM ended the session. The DM *assured us* that we didn't have to create new characters.

The only character who did not succumb to the paralysis is the Druid, who has no way to remove the paralysis. Is there a way for the Druid to cure the rest of the group?  Will it most likely be fixed by the DM introducing an outside NPC who happens to wander into us?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67858/discussion-on-question-by-trephination-how-do-we-break-out-of-paralysis).

Answer (score 15):

Have the druid cast "protection from poison" or "Lesser Restoration" on everyone. If he doesn't have either readied then he needs effectively take a long rest and ready one of them. At lv 5 he has 5 uses of either(3 lv 2 slots and 2 lv 3 slots).

Lesser Restoration

> You touch a creature and can end either one disease or one condition
>   afflicting it. The condition can be blinded, deafened, paralyzed, or
>   poisoned.

Protection from Poison

> You touch a creature. If it is poisoned, you neutralize the poison. If
>   more than one poison afflicts the target, you neutralize one poison
>   that you know is present, or you neutralize one at random.
>
> For the duration, the target has advantage on saving throws against
>   being poisoned, and it has resistance to poison damage.

Based on the 1st sentence this is a venom induced paralysis, and thus should be covered by both spells. If you have a party of more than 6 people(including the druid) this will take you 16 hours to heal everyone, unless you got another caster with aforementioned spell options. If you heal the mentioned ranger first, he too should be able to cast either spell.

Now if the paralysis is caused by more magical means then you want "Dispell Magic", a 3rd level spell.

> Choose any creature, object, or magical effect within range. Any spell
>   of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level
>   or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting
>   ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell’s level. On a successful check,
>   the spell ends

That would be 2 uses per 8 hours of rest. Since your DM has assured you it ain't a TPK yet, Ima assume it is non magical venom.

Comment: It's important to note that RAW, dispel magic only ends spells. Even if the venom is magical, it would be well within DM purview to say that dispel magic is ineffective.

Comment: If the party is too big It will take **one day + 8 hours** to heal everyone, not 16 hours. You can only get one long rest every 24 hours. There are no consecutive long rests. `A character can’t benefit from more than one long rest in a 24-hour period`

Answer (score 11):

There is one spell available<sup>1</sup> to 5th Level Druids that deals with the *[paralyzed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/appendices#Paralyzed) condition*:

***[Lesser Restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lesser-restoration)*** is a 2nd level spell that explicitly cures the paralyzed condition. It is available to Bards, Clerics, Druids, Paladins, and Rangers. Clerics and Druids know all the spells on their lists, and can therefore prepare them, while the others are more limited.

A 5th Level Druid has three 2nd-level spell slots and two 3rd-level slots. If the druid doesn't have *Lesser Restoration* prepared, it needs a *long rest* to prepare it. At that point, the Druid could remove paralysis from five people. He would need to wait another day before taking an additional long rest to recover more spell slots.

If the druid is *Circle of the Land*, it has **[Natural Recovery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/druid#Natural%20Recovery)**, allowing it to recover one 2nd-level spell slot during a *Short Rest* (at its current class level). If the druid already had *Lesser Restoration* prepared and hasn't used **Natural Recovery** since its last long rest, it can cast it once after an hour. If not, a long rest will get it five castings, with an additional casting one hour after that.

<sup>1</sup><sub>A generous GM may also allow the "neutralize poison" aspect of *[Protection from Poison](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-poison)* because the paralysis is "poisonous" in nature, but RAW doesn't support it and *Lesser Restoration* explicitly does the job.
 This monster already seems a house-rule creation, so it's possible.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

### You likely just need to wait a bit

For example look at the poison from a [Giant Centipede](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-centipede), which seems to behave similar to what you describe:

> The target must succeed on a DC 11 Constitution saving throw or take 10 (3d6) poison damage. If the poison damage reduces the target to 0 hit points, the target is stable but poisoned for 1 hour, even after regaining hit points, and is paralyzed while poisoned in this way.

It seems that the most likely thing that will happen is that after an hour or so of in game time, the poison wears off and you can move again.